# Extract Values from key and array on JSON begins with '['

Tags: arrays, json, delphi, pascal

**Sorry**, I searched here for This problem on the site
But the Json I have is unlike any other here on the site Because it begins with '['

and I got tired trying to extract the values
Then how I can Extract Values from key and array on JSON begins with '['

```
[{"date":"12/11/1990","name":"Delphi7"},{"date":"03/05/2012","name":"Delphi 10.4"}]
```

Or extract Form This :

```
[{"User":{"date":"12/11/1990","name":"Delphi7"}},{"User":{"date":"03/05/2012","name":"Delphi 10.4"}}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSON, `[]` denotes an **array**. In this case, both examples you have provided represent an array of objects.

If you parse these strings using [`TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue), it will return a `TJSONValue` pointer to a [`TJSONArray`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONArray) object that is holding [`TJSONObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject) elements, eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., System.JSON;

var
  JSONStr, DateStr, NameStr: string;
  JSONVal: TJSONValue;
  JSONArr: TJSONArray;
  JSONObj: TJSONObject;
  I: Integer;
begin
  JSONStr := '[{"date":"12/11/1990","name":"Delphi7"},{"date":"03/05/2012","name":"Delphi 10.4"}]';
  JSONVal := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSONStr);
  try
    JSONArr := JSONVal as TJSONArray;
    for I := 0 to JSONArr.Count-1 do
    begin
      JSONObj := JSONArr[I] as TJSONObject;
      DateStr := JSONObj.GetValue('date').Value;
      NameStr := JSONObj.GetValue('name').Value;
      ...
    end;
  finally
    JSONVal.Free;
  end;
end;
```

```pascal
uses
  ..., System.JSON;

var
  JSONStr, DateStr, NameStr: string;
  JSONVal: TJSONValue;
  JSONArr: TJSONArray;
  JSONObj, JSONUser: TJSONObject;
  I: Integer;
begin
  JSONStr := '[{"User":{"date":"12/11/1990","name":"Delphi7"}},{"User":{"date":"03/05/2012","name":"Delphi 10.4"}}]';
  JSONVal := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSONStr);
  try
    JSONArr := JSONVal as TJSONArray;
    for I := 0 to JSONArr.Count-1 do
    begin
      JSONObj := JSONArr[I] as TJSONObject;
      JSONUser := JSONObj.GetValue('User') as TJSONObject;
      DateStr := JSONUser.GetValue('date').Value;
      NameStr := JSONUser.GetValue('name').Value;
      ...
    end;
  finally
    JSONVal.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Remy Lebeau
It didn't work for me until after this change
JSONObj := JSONArr.Items[I] as TJSONObject;
DateStr := JSONObj.GetValue('date').Value;
NameStr := JSONObj.GetValue('name').Value;

Comment: Fixed the `Get()`, thanks. `JSONArr.Items[I]` and `JSONArr[I]` do the same thing, as `Items[]` is the [`default` property](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties_(Delphi)#Array_Properties) of `TJSONArray`.

Comment: all Respect and appreciation for you